# Python script to manipulate text is writing [ ]+ to text file instead of [ \t]+

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have made a python script to read lines from a file called input.txt and output them to output.txt with some changes in formating.

Here is the code here:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
towrite = open("output.txt", "a")
for term in lines:
    for char in term:
        towrite.write(char+"[ \t]+")
    towrite.write("|")
towrite.close()
```

If input.txt just has a single line with the characters "ab", output.txt should have "a[ \t]+b[ \t]+|" but instead has "a[  ]+b[    ]+|". I think it is replacing \t with a tab, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, turned out I just needed to fix this line:

Change `towrite.write(char+"[ \t]+")`
To `towrite.write(char+"[ \\t]+")`